# Variable and mktime() not working

Tags: php, variables, mktime

I have the following code:

```
$search = '3,39,49,5,5,2012';
$search = mktime($search);
echo $search;
```

That just outputs the current timestamp, not the one for the date specified. However if I do the following:

```
$search = mktime(3,39,49,5,5,2012);
echo $search;
```

It outputs the correct timestamp, 1336203589. Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
$search = '3,39,49,5,5,2012';
$search = call_user_func_array('mktime',explode(',', $search));
echo $search;
```

Demo: http://codepad.viper-7.com/lxTJbO

Answer (score 1):

mktime expects an array of time values, so you have just to split your array with `explode` oder `preg_split`

```
$search = '3,39,49,5,5,2012';
$t = explode(',', $search);
$search = mktime($t[0], $t[1], $t[2], $t[3], $t[4], $t[5]);
```

Answer (score 1):

That is because you need to specify a list of integers to `mktime`. You are passing a `string` to it (which for your understanding is a list, but not so for the php interpretor). You need to convert it to such a list:

```
$search = '3,39,49,5,5,2012';
$search = mktime(explode(',', $search));
echo $search;
```

Comment: That doesn't work, I just get the error `Warning: mktime() expects parameter 1 to be long, array given on line 3`

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry. I made a mistake there. You need to call the function with a list of parameters, I was calling it with a list as its only parameter. What you need to do is `call_user_func_array('mktime', explode(',', $search));`